# Cannot use QuerySet for "\"User\": Use a QuerySet for \"User\"."

Tags: python, django, request

I am working on a django project, python version 3.8 with django version 3.2.3 and I have created a friend request model that currently only needs to make a friend request table entry. The request contains two parameters, the senders unique id, and the receiver's unique id. It then makes a friend request entry in the FriendshipRequest table (as described by the model shown below). The view.py is as shown below.

```py
@csrf_exempt
def friend_request(request):
  if request.method != 'POST':
    return r.method_not_allow_405()
  
  try:
    client_json = json.loads(request.body)
    sent_user_id = client_json['sent_user_id']
    received_user_id = client_json['received_user_id']

    sent_user = models.User.objects.filter(unique_id=sent_user_id)
    received_user = models.User.objects.filter(unique_id=received_user_id)

    try:
      models.Friend.objects.add_friend(sent_user=sent_user, received_user=received_user, message="")
      return r.json_response(0, "friend request successful")
    except Exception as e:
      return r.json_response(-2, str(e)) # 
  except Exception as e:
    return r.json_response(-2, str(e)) # catch errors made by sent_user, received_user lines, or json (no errors in this case)
```

There are four main models defined, the User which represents the User information, I've only kept the relevant unique_id variable in the snippet. The FriendshipRequest model which represents a friend request, and uses a ForeignKey for the user that sent the request and the user that received it. There is a FriendshipManager model that manages friend request, and in this snippet only contains add_friend function, which in turn, should create a FriendshipRequest entry.The Friend model represents friendship.

```py
class User(models.Model):
  unique_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.unique_id

class FriendshipRequest(models.Model):
  '''model to represent friendship request'''

  sent_user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="friendship_request_sent")
  received_user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="friendship_request_received")
  message = models.TextField("message", blank=True)
  

  class Meta:
    verbose_name = _("Friendship Request")
    verbose_name_plural = _("Friendship Requests")
    unique_together = ("sent_user", "received_user")

  def __str__(self):
    return "friend request"

class FriendshipManager(models.Manager):
  '''model to manage friendship status'''
  unique_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
  created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

  def add_friend(self, sent_user, received_user, message=None):
    ''' create friendship request'''
    if sent_user == received_user:
      raise ValidationError("users cannot be friends with themselves")


    if FriendshipRequest.objects.filter(sent_user=sent_user, received_user=received_user).exists():
      raise AlreadyFriendsError("users are already friends")

    if FriendshipRequest.objects.filter(sent_user=received_user, received_user=sent_user).exists():
      raise AlreadyExistsError("this user already requested friendship from you")

    if message is None:
      message = ""
   
    request, created = FriendshipRequest.objects.get_or_create(
        sent_user=sent_user, received_user=received_user
    )

    if created is False:
      raise AlreadyExistsError("friendship already requested")

    if message:
      request.message = message
      request.save()

    return request

class Friend(models.Model):
  '''model to represent friends'''
  sent_user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.CASCADE, related_name="friends")
  received_user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.CASCADE, related_name="not_friends")
 
  objects = FriendshipManager()

  class Meta:
    verbose_name = _("Friend")
    verbose_name_plural = _("Friends")
    unique_together = ("sent_user", "received_user")

  def __str__(self):
    return "User #%s is friends with #%s" % (self.to_user_username, self.from_user_username)
```

where

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
```

and in settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODAL = 'api.User'
```

It seems that the error is occurs right here

```
 if FriendshipRequest.objects.filter(sent_user=sent_user, received_user=received_user).exists():
      raise AlreadyFriendsError("users are already friends")

    if FriendshipRequest.objects.filter(sent_user=received_user, received_user=sent_user).exists():
      raise AlreadyExistsError("this user already requested friendship from you")
```

resulting in the

```
 "Cannot use QuerySet for \"User\": Use a QuerySet for \"User\"."
```

I am extremely confused about this error and do not know how to solve it, any help?

Comment: Please check where do you import that `models.User` from: `sent_user = models.User.objects.filter()`

Comment: I assume it could be anothr models you are using here and for `FriendshipRequest`